# ipython magic/macro/alias guidance for invoking shell and dispatching result

Tags: ipython

(Note: I have plenty of python and unix shell experience, but fairly new to ipython -- using 7.5)

I'm trying to replicate a UNIX shell function that I use all the time, so that it works in the ipython shell.

The requirement is that I want to type something like `to myproj`, and then have ipython process the resulting text by doing a `cd` to the directory that comes back from `to`.  *(This is a quick-directory-change utility I use in unix)*

The way it works in unix is that a shell function invokes an external command, that command prints its result to stdout, and the shell function then invokes the internal `cd` to the target dir.

I've been trying to wrap my head around `%magic` and macros and aliases in ipython, but so far I don't see how to get this done.  Any ideas?

Comment: does [this](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html) help?

Comment: How about capturing `!` system command output in a list? https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/shell.html#string-lists

Comment: @jeschwar:  might help.  Thanks, I'll study it.

Comment: @hpaulj:  the theme of that link is right up my alley -- I want to use ipython as a part-time unix shell.  Not to abandon bash, but a sort of hybrid bash/python working environment.  I'm assuming that when I understand ipython in depth, this will be straightforward.